# How to change height of suggestion options in monaco editor

Tags: css, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I want to change the height of the rows in the autocomplete menu in Monaco editor. It looks like they are using absolute positioning to handle the list by setting an explicit `top` value for each `row`. Is there any way to change this height?

I have tried using custom CSS to solve it but since each row has its `top` value generated at runtime, I'm not sure that CSS can solve this problem.

[image: Reference]